# Не понимаю как работает интерполяция в Unity, в частности Lerp и Slerp

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Часто приходиться использовать Lerp для плавности, практически во всем. Но мне вообще не понятно описание, которое дано в документации, там говориться, что Lerp возвращает путь от первого аргумента до второго и для этого существует третий аргумент, который интерполирует его позицию от 0 до 1(то есть 0,5 это середина между точками).

Но непонятность в том, что я вообще редко так его использую чаще всего в третий аргумент, вписываю Time.deltaTime умноженный на какое-нибудь число и все работает. И получается так, что данный третий аргумент просто не равен промежутку от 0 до 1, а больше его в несколько раз. И в документации написано другое, и ещё LerpUnclamped есть, который вроде и создан для того чтобы выходит за промежуток от 0 до 1.

Мозг взрывается от не понимания, что же это за аргумент t, время или же процентное соотношение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lerp - линейная интерполяция, реализует формулу

```
C = A * (1-t) + B * t
```

При изменении параметра `t` от нуля до единицы мы находимся в промежуточных точках отрезка `AB`. А если этот параметр вне диапазона 0..1 - то мы находимся на **прямой** `AB` вне указанного отрезка. В этом случае интерполяция - на совсем правильный термин - то уже экстраполяция. Но ничего страшного в этом нет, если не нарушается логика или физика процесса движения.

Если известно время `T` равномерного прямолинейного движения от `A` к `B`, то в момент `t*T` толчка находится в соответствующем положении внутри отрезка

Comment: Спасибо, стало немного понятнее. То есть обычный Lerp может делать тоже, что и LerpUnclamped?

Comment: Это зависит от реализации - судя по вашему описанию - внутри это одно и то же. Документация  говорит о том, что `parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1]` -  но что происходит при t=2 или -1? Возвращаются при этом крайние точки отрезка или вне его? Мне не на чем проверить